# Error de "NoReverseMatch at" con pruebas de "django.contrib.auth.views.login"

Tags: python, django

Quisiera autenticar usuarios utilizando `django.contrib.auth.views.login`.

Quiero que cuando sea correcto el login los mande a un `dashboard`. Tengo los siguientes codigos:

En settings:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/usuarios/dashboard/'
```

En Urls Aplicacion:

```
url(r'^usuarios/', include('Usuarios.urls', namespace='usuarios')),
url(r'^login/$','django.contrib.auth.views.login',{'template_name' : 'admin/login.html',},name='login'),
```

En Usuarios/Urls :

```
url(r'^dashboard/$', BlankView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

En Usuarios/View :

```
class BlankView(TemplateView):
template_name = '/templates/index.html'
```

A la hora de hacer pruebas me sale bien el formulario de login pero al dar aceptar me manda el siguiente error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /usuarios/dashboard/

Reverse for 'logout' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost/usuarios/dashboard/
Django Version:     1.9
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'logout' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Comment: César... y si es en django 1.9? cómo cambian las líneas de éste tipo? `url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name' : 'admin/login.html'})`

Comment: Cesar, Justo como comentas existe en mi template una linea que me provoca ese error:

<a href="{% url 'usuarios:logout' %}">

anterior mente ya las habia comentado

<!-- <li><a href="{% url 'usuarios:logout' %}"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                    </li> -->

Answer (score 3):

En django 1.9 se utiliza en el patron urls.py:

```
url(r'^login/$', views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, {'next_page': '/login/'}, name='logout'),
```

en logout la rediriges a la pagina que quieras con netx_page.

En settings.py pon las url a las que quieras redirigir tambien:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/index/'
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
```

En login.html puedes cerrar sesion con algo asi:

```
<p>Estas logueado con el usuario {{ user.username|capfirst }}, <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">cerrar sesion</a></p>
```

Asi esta deprecado:

```
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name' : 'admin/login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/login/'}, name='logout'),
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo más probable es que en el template de dashboard tengas algún enlace para salir del sistema (`logout`), asegurate de definir correctamente la ruta en tus URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name' : 'admin/login.html'}),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/login/'}),
    # ...
]
```

Con esto la redirección debería funcionar bien:

```
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>> reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.login')
'/login/'
>>> reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.logout')
'/logout/'
```

También, puedes usar [`name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) en tus URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name' : 'admin/login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/login/'}, name='logout'),
    # ...
]
```

Y ahora puedes usar `reverse` usando el parámetro `name` de tus URLs:

```
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>> reverse('login')
'/login/'
>>> reverse('logout')
'/logout/'
```

Creo que el error se está dando porque en el template debes estar usando algo como esto:

```
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Salir</a>
```

Con la última solución ya no debería darte problemas.

Comment: Justo como comentas existe en mi template una linea que me provoca ese error:
anterior mente ya las habia comentado

    <!-- href="{% url 'usuarios:logout' %}"-->

pero no se porque seguía el error, hoy haciendo mas pruebas decidí borrar la linea para asegurar que no la tome encuenta y esa fue la solucion, pareciera que esa no es la forma correcta de comentar en el html aunque siempre me funciono.

si me pueden asesorar para saber cual es la forma correcta de comentar codigo en el html.

Gracias.

Comment: @Rocke no importa que la comentes, Django igual lo renderiza por eso es que te sigue saliendo el error, si la URL es de la forma `usuarios:logout` es porque estás usando namespaces

Comment: Correcto, pregunta solucionada. Quite la linea usuarios:logout porque de todos modos estaba mal, pero también probé el método reverse() el cual también es funcional. Gracias Cesar.